# Unable to position Rectangle in Canvas in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm new to SL.  I just wrote a simple app drawing a Rectangle and Line.  When I try to position the Rectangle it has no effect and always puts it in the lower-right corner:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(r, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(r, 100);
```

When I try to use SetValue, the app hangs (ie. get stuck on the loading animation in the browser):

```
r.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 10);
r.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 10);
```

Has anyone experienced anything like this, and/or know how to get past it?

[EDIT] Here's the more complete source:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle() {
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            Width = 100,
            Height = 20,
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush { Color = Color.FromArgb(80, 143, 12, 28) }
        };
        //r.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 10);
        //r.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 10);
        Canvas.SetLeft(r, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(r, 100);
        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(r);

        var line = new Line() {
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            X1 = 10, Y1 = 10, X2 = 100, Y2 = 200
        };
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(line);
    }
```

I've tried putting the LayoutRoot..Add call before the SetValue/SetLeft but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I know this may seem like a silly question, but are your drawn elements actually within a canvas element, which is itself within the root visual ?

Comment: Not a silly question, especially since I said this is my first SL app :-)
I've added the more complete source above.

Comment: What happens if you don't attempt to position the rectangle at all?  What happens if you place the definition for the rectangle in Xaml?

Comment: Not position (or trying, with the method above) puts it in some default position... it's always the same from run to run.  I do have *a* rectangle in XAML, but there point here was I need to do it in C#.  Answer below was that I should have been adding it to the canvas' children, not the LayoutRoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(r);
        Canvas.SetLeft(r, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(r, 100);
```

Rather than:

```
        Canvas.SetLeft(r, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(r, 100);
        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(r);
```

Update : It got fixed since in XAML it is by default a grid tag as LayoutRoot. After changing it to a canvas tag and it no longer gets stuck.

Comment: I did, but it didn't make any difference.  The same with when I used SetValue; it hung when called both before and after the LayoutRoot.Children.Add call.

Comment: LayoutRoot is a Canvas right ? because by default it is a Grid.

Comment: Ah!!  That was the problem.  I changed LayoutRoot to canvas1 and it works.  I should have noticed that the line was drawing off the canvas.

The SetValue approach is still hanging, though I guess I'll get use SetLeft instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Also you should generally put such code in the OnLoaded Event handler :) (although after InitializeComponent is generally safe but you might get layout Errors) All the best on this beautiful journey of WPF

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip.  Yeah, I'm just experimenting at this stage.  Trying to work out if I'll use HTML5+js/jQuery, Flash, or Silverlight for a RIA.  Silverlight currently winning the battle.

Comment: http://basaratali.blogspot.com/2010/11/ways-in-which-silverlight-4-is-superior.html should be useful ;)